# C# - Using File.WriteAllLines

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Will the below method overwrite the output file (process.txt) ?

```
private static void CompareOrig()
{

    File.WriteAllLines("process.txt",
    File.ReadAllLines("process2.txt").Except(File.ReadAllLines("process.txt")));

}
```

**Added Info:**

The problem is that when the lines are read from process2.txt, they are written to the process.txt file, hence overwriting all existing data in that file. Instead how could I append the output to process.txt? e.g.

```
File.AppendAllText("process.txt")
```

Comment: Since this is really simple - why don't you try it yourself?
If that is the case, maybe read all lines into variable, then rewrite that and the new data?

Comment: AppendAllText, AppendAllLines are existing methods.

Comment: @Henk Holterman Thanks,  i used AppendAllLines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will the below method overwrite the output file (process.txt) ?

Yes

> If so, how can this be avoided?

Use another filename for writing.

If you meant "will it be overwritten before it is completely read" then the answer is No and you have no problem.

But splitting this up with one or two variables would make it so much more readable. If it makes you doubt, so will it make the reader. Over and over again.

Comment: Thanks, how could I then "add" or append the file?

Comment: Is your question about accomplishing file I/O or about subtle C# sequence issues?  Please be clear. There is an _Edit_ link under your question.

Answer (score -2):

A little old, but for anyone reading. 
If you only want to append to existing file use.

```
File.WriteLine("Text");
```

instead of

```
File.WriteAllLines("Text);
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `System.IO.File.WriteLine()`. There _is_ `StreamWriter.WriteLine()`, but if you check OP's question again, they did not first create a StreamWriter. Thus, whenever OP mention `File`, they were referring to `System.IO.File`.