# How to write all text as lines from a table

Tags: c#, file

I have a particular issue. I have a data table which I want to have its data written to a text file. For this (I had already treat this in a previous tread) I used:

```
DataTable table = MyLibrary.dtRawData;

var fileLines = table
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(row => String.Join("  ", row.ItemArray))
  .Where(line => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line));

try
{
    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, fileLines);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
}
```

My problem is the `WriteAllLines` function seems to always *append* data, if the file exists, but what I need is the file to be *rewritten* if already present at current location.What can I change from the code, in order to assure the file is overwritten and not appended?
Regards.

Comment: Can't you just check if the file exists, and delete it if it does?

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines` will always overwrite the file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398808/c-sharp-using-file-writealllines Your problem must be somewhere else in code

Comment: @Edin: Thanks so much. It seems I didn't "purge" the data from my table; each time I press the generate Text button, it adds the same data to the table, therefore I thought the method appends the data, but in fact was the table which had caused problems. Many thanks

Comment: It looks quite OK, since it's `File.AppendAllLines` that *appends* the file.

Answer (score 2):

The `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines` method will overwrite an existing file with a new file if it has the same name in the same directory.

If you run the below lines of code consecutively

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\{user}\Desktop\test.txt", new string[] { "e", "f", "g", "h" });

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\{user}\Desktop\test.txt", new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" });
```

you will end up with one file containing the following content:

a
b
c
d